# Need to assemble a matrix from several ASCII GRD files

Tags: excel, mosaic, ascii, surfer

I am totally new to GIS software.

I would like to consolidate 205 ASCII GRDs files (the file format of Golden Software's "Surfer") into a single big GRD file or just a big matrix of (about 2400 rows by 2400 columns) I can manipulate within Excel.

Each of the 205 GRDs contain mean windspeed (32 bit float) information of 150x150 cells. I could import these GRDs one by one in Excel but I thought there could be a faster way to do this (I actually have 5 other parameters in this same GRD format).

I was able to put these 205 GRD files in one Arcmap layer using the "Mosaic to New Layer" tool but I didn't find a way to export this layer to a single GRD. I haven't tried the same in QGIS.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After mosaicing using the Mosaic to New Raster tool, export to ASCII Grid using the [Raster to ASCII](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/raster-to-ascii.htm) tool which:

> Converts a raster dataset to an ASCII text file representing raster data.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Surfer (or the free Surfer trial version), you can do this in Surfer too and it's really quite easy:

1. Open Surfer (current version is v18)
2. Click **Grids | Resize | Mosaic**.
3. In the **Open Grid(s)** dialog, select all 205 grids. You can hold the
   SHIFT key down, click the first grid and then click the last grid
   and they'll all be selected.
4. Click **Open**.
5. In the **Grid Mosaic** dialog, change any options you want (including export file format, if you prefer a list of XYZ points or a Surfer GRD) and just click **OK**. The single grid is created.

Thanks!
Kari